# Map Creation in SpriteKit (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-development

i have a problem i cant find anything to create a topview map that creates with code randomly and have items that can be clicked

Have anybody Experience with that and can help me?

Thanks and best Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: How about this? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/games/how-to-create-a-random-terrain-tile-map-using-sktilemapnode-and-gkperlinnoisesource